# Android ListView

Tags: android, listview

Добрый день.
Такой вопрос. Реализовал что-то типо чата с помощью ListView. Каждую секунду программа проверяет нет ли новых данных и добавляет выполняет `listSimple.setAdapter(Adapter);`
Экран перемещается к центру списка, в итоге неудобства. Необходимо чтоб на экране всегда был конец списка. Прописывал `android:transcriptMode="normal"`. Толку 0.

Спасибо!

Comment: данный метод, к сожалению, плавно прокручивает до определенной позиции.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь не мотает при каждом обновлении, но на одну ячейку вниз не хочет двигать (smoothScrollToPosition)

Comment: Одному мне непонятно, зачем постоянно вызывать setAdapter() ? По-моему проще вызвать notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Устанавливайте адаптер следующим образом:

```
Parcelable state = yourListView.onSaveInstanceState();
yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
yourListView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
```

Таким образом, `ListView` при установке нового адаптера сохранит свою текущую позицию скролла. Нужно это для того, чтобы при добавлении нового элемента в список, не приходилось прокручивать полностью весь `ListView` от начала до конца.

Далее, вам потребуется промотать на один элемент вниз, для этого подойдёт метод [`smoothScrollToPosition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)), как вам уже посоветовали в ответе выше.

Если же анимация скроллинга нежелательна (а вы её получите при использовании вышеуказанного метода), то:

```
yourListView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        yourListView.setSelection(pos);
        View v = yourListView.getChildAt(position);
        if (v != null) {
            v.requestFocus();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

используй метод ListView
[smothScrollToPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int))